# python download image from url and thumbnail and resize

Tags: python

I am still new at programming and working on a school assignment were I have to find an image from a website and have it save to a specific folder on my drive as well as thumbnail and resize the image to be smaller. I can't have the specific folder hard coded. It has to pull up a search for file area. Any help will be greatly appreciated. This is what I got so far but I am so lost from here.

```
import urllib
def myCreate():
    """
    myCreate(): function pulls a picture from the internet and creates a thumbnail and saves it to my computer.
    """
    path = setMediaPath()
    data = urllib.urlretrieve("https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Savannah-cat-long-body-shot.jpg", path + "myPicture.jpg")
    file = getMediaPath("myPicture.jpg")
    picture = makePicture(file)
myCreate()
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing right now?

Comment: It will pop up the search for file but as soon as I hit okay it just ends and never even saves the image

Comment: Can you post more code to check `setMediaPath()` what it does and how it does it. And as well for `getMediaPath(..)` and `makePicture(file)`?  I guess there might be something missing there or you might have to call some other methods that we are not aware here of their existence in your assignment project.

Comment: Might be a permission issue–make sure you can write to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

**First, we need to download the image then convert it as a thumbnail and resize the image to be smaller:**

```
# install glob using pip install glob3
# and PIL using  pip install Pillow
import urllib.request as req
from PIL import Image
# dont forget to put the img url here
imgurl ="https://-------------.jpg"
req.urlretrieve(imgurl, "image_name.jpg")
import glob
# get all the jpg files from the current folder
for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
  im = Image.open(infile)
  # convert to thumbnail image
  im.thumbnail((128, 128), Image.ANTIALIAS)
  # don't save if thumbnail already exists
  if infile[0:2] != "T_":
    # prefix thumbnail file with T_
    im.save("T_" + infile, "JPEG")
```